# Removing iframe from page

Tags: javascript, iframe

I am creating an iframe dynamically for submmiting a form,after submitting i need to remove the iframe form the page.I removed itas follows but it is not removed,

```
function remove(){
 var frame = document.getElementById("upload_iframe"),
 var frameDoc = frame.contentDocument || frame.contentWindow.document;
 frameDoc.removeChild(frameDoc.documentElement);
}
```

How to remove the ifarme form the form completely.

Thanks

Comment: have you tried `document.removeChild(frame);` ?

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.` .. my suggestion `var temp = document.querySelectorAll('iframe')[X]; temp.parentNode.removeChild(temp);` X = number position.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Frame has 2 behaviors: frame as document element (like div or another DOM element) and frame as window element (like global `window` object). So if you want to remove iframe from DOM tree you have to work with iframe like with DOM element

```
function remove(){
 var frame = document.getElementById("upload_iframe");
 frame.parentNode.removeChild(frame);
}
```

Comment: but what if i have the remove function written inside the frame only, and want to perform some operation after removing ?

Comment: @ArunPratapSingh you can send message to parent frame via postMessage and ask parent window to remove iframe

Answer (score 1):

A way I've been doing it (since I have a large amount of iframes) is using jQuery,

```
$('iframe').remove()
```

or in the case of only one iframe you can remove it using its ID, still with jQuery

```
$('#iframeID').remove()
```