# kill/destroy iframe forcefully

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I want to add an event listener to kill/destroy the following `iframe` forcefully when cancel button is clicked.

can someone help me with this?

```
var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
iframe.id = "hidden_iframe";
iframe.style.display = "none";
iframe.src = 'url.html';
iframe.hidden = true;
document.body.appendChild(iframe);
```

Comment: Not sure what you meant by event listener or by kill/destroy the iframe. If you just want to remove the iframe from your page you can create a [function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12419522/843297) to do so, that is called in the onclick event from the cancel button.

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you are looking for?

```js
function create() {
  var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
  iframe.id = "hidden_iframe";
  //iframe.style.display = "none";
  iframe.src = 'https://www.bootstrapcdn.com/';
  //iframe.hidden = true;
  document.body.appendChild(iframe);
}

function kill() {
  iframe = document.getElementById('hidden_iframe');
  iframe.parentNode.removeChild(iframe);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="create()">Create iframe</button>

<button onclick="kill()">Kill iframe</button>
<br/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Define this within your cancel function:

```
cancel.onclick = function() {
    kill_iframe()
}
```

Then define this function:

```
const kill_iframe = () => {
    let iframe = document.getElementedById("hidden_iframe")
    iframe.parentNode.removeChild(iframe)
}
```