# Blazor: using pdfjs in iframe creates multiple instances

Tags: blazor, pdf.js

I have a **Blazor** app (WASM). In it I use **mozilla pdf.js inside a iframe**.
I call this iframe from different pages and component.
At the Chrome Developer Tools in Source I see, that each time I enter a page where the iframe is used a new instance is created and after leaving the instance is not killed.
So while acting on the website the user creates more and more instances and I'm afraid, it will fill the RAM.
**How can I kill the instances before leaving a page** (to another page)**?**

```
<iframe id="pdfViewer" src="_content/Somiso.Net.PdfViewer/lib/pdfjs/web/viewer.html" style="@Style"></iframe> (WASM)
```

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59978395/7149454

Comment: @NickKovalsky Nope, using this code makes no difference. Thanks.